# Importing data from Excel to MySQL showing text in different language

Tags: php, mysql, excel, file, import

I am trying to import data from Excel to MySQL using PHP. The code I am using imports the data but the language is strange.

Below is the PHP code:

```
<?php

    include_once("conn.php");
    $filename= "Financial Sample.xlsx";
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");

    $count = 0;                                         // add this line
    while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        //print_r($emapData[0]);
        //exit();
        $count++;                                      // add this line

        if($count>1){                                  // add this line

        //echo html_entity_decode("žūų");

        //echo json_encode($emapData[0]);
         $insert_q = "INSERT into questions(q_describe) values ('$emapData[0]')";
        if($query_q=$mysqli->query($insert_q))
        {
            $final=array();
            $final['status']="success";
            $final['message']="Inserted Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            $er = $mysqli->error;
             $final['status']=$er;
            $final['message']="Error";
        } 

        echo json_encode($final);
        }                                              // add this line
    } 
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Once imported, data is seen like this in phpMyAdmin:

[image]

Actual Excel is shown below:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

### Edit

Showing the structure of my table:

[image]

Comment: It looks like an encoding error to me

Comment: and how do i correct it  ?

Comment: What is `$mysqli`? How was it instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the structure of your table, you're looking for two fields: encoding and Collation.

[image]

Make sure they're set to cp1252 West European and latin1_swedish_ci respectively.

Comment: i have edited the question and showed structure of my table, i can see collation but i dont see encoding anywhere